# Can I persist a User ID for an anonymous user when they upgrade to a new iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, identity

I'm looking for a second opinion on an issue.

Scenario: A iOS app user is issued a unique ID upon first launch by a backend platform. Consider this ID to be roughly sequential - or at least not derived anything device-specific - and anonymous. The user has not "logged in" in any way, but may have explicitly provided some information that is being stored platform-side related to this ID.

Now, the user buys a new iPhone, and restores a backup of their previous device to the new device. I'm being advised there is no way to persist that unique ID to the new device, and thus link them to the stored platform data. That the only way this could work would be to have the user specifically provide a "login" function before the new device, and then use that same login to associate the user to their ID in the platform.

Is there really no way to persist a simple piece of data across a device upgrade in iOS anymore? thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Perhaps look at storing the value in iCloud

Comment: Thanks. Does that require any user permissions, or is that just an available mechanism for users with icloud logins?